# How to dynamically change the ContentURL of a page-worker for Firefox Add-on?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox-addon

I am working on a simple dictionary add-on that allows the user to highlight a word (by double-clicking on it), which will cause a popup displaying a dictionary definition of the word to appear.

I am having trouble dynamically changing the ContentURL of the page-worker that I am using so that I can access its DOM and scrape the definition from it.
I have tried both dynamically changing the URL of a single page-worker, as well as creating a page-worker each time a new word is selected, sending the information to the addon, then destroying the page-worker.

Here is my code(for the second idea):

define.js:

```
$(window).dblclick(function() {
    var selected = getSelected();
    if (selected!="") {
        calldictionary(selected);
        var completedURL = "http://www.dictionary.com/browse/" + selected;
        $('#define').dialog("open");
        createPageWorker(completedURL);

    }
});

function getSelected() {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        return window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection) {
        return document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return '';
}
```

definitionsender.js:

```
var sendInformation = "var elements = document.querySelectorAll('div.def-set > div'); " +
                      "for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {" +
                      " postMessage(elements[i].textContent) " +
                      "}" +
                      "self.destroy();";

function createPageWorker(URL){

    dictionaryReference.Page({
        contentScriptWhen: "ready",
        contentScriptFile: [
            data.url("jquery.js"),
            data.url("jquery-ui.min.js"),
            data.url("define.js"),
            data.url("definitionsender.js")
        ],
        contentURL: URL,
        contentScript: sendInformation,
        onMessage: "function(message){"+
        "console.log(message);}"
    });
}
```

If I were using my first idea, the line

```
createPageWorker(completedURL);
```

would be replaced with the line

```
dictionaryReference.contentURL = completedURL;
```

to a page-worker "dictionaryReference" contained in my index.js file.

Please do not simply post links to MDN; I've read through all of the relevant documentation and it has not given me much guidance.

Comment: Any error messages? What did the [debugger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Add-on_Debugger) say? And could you post the whole code, with the `require('sdk/page-worker')` and all? (or at the minimum indicate which of these are content scripts, and which are add-on scripts?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts (forgive me for posting the MDN docs ;-) ):

> - the add-on's main code, including "main.js" and other modules in "lib", **can use the SDK high-level and low-level APIs**, but can't
>     access web content directly
> - content scripts **can't use the SDK's APIs** (no access to globals exports, require) but can access web content

It seems as though you are trying to access `createPageWorker()` from `define.js`, which seems to be a content script. This is forbidden by the separation of concerns. The way to communicate would be to use something like

```
self.port.emit("createPageWorker", URL);
```

in the content script, and listen to that message via

```
self.port.on("createPageWorker", function(URL) { 
    // do something here
);
```

in the add-on code (`index.js` or whatever).